# unable to install Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 5.0.0 on VS2017 Cummunity (V15.5.2)

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I would like to use the latest toolkit but When I try to install the toolkit (using Manage NuGet Package...), I get these messages. What I did wrong?

Installing Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 5.0.0.

Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 5.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.15063 (UAP,Version=v10.0.15063).

Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 5.0.0 supports: uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299)

Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 5.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.15063 (UAP,Version=v10.0.15063) / win10-arm.

Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 5.0.0 supports: uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299)

Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 5.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.15063 (UAP,Version=v10.0.15063) / win10-arm-aot.

Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 5.0.0 supports: uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299)

Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 5.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.15063 (UAP,Version=v10.0.15063) / win10-x64.

Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 5.0.0 supports: uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299)

Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 5.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.15063 (UAP,Version=v10.0.15063) / win10-x64-aot.

Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 5.0.0 supports: uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299)

Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 5.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.15063 (UAP,Version=v10.0.15063) / win10-x86.

Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 5.0.0 supports: uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299)

Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 5.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.15063 (UAP,Version=v10.0.15063) / win10-x86-aot.

Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 5.0.0 supports: uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299)

Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'CommandBar'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Method 1

As the error states the  Microsoft.Toolkit version 5.0.0 doesn't support platform minimum target version 15063(Creator's Update). So kindly change your project's **Min version**. so then it will work fine.

**Right-click on your project -> Properties->Application->Min Version ->16299**

[image]

#### Method 2

If you don't want to lose support for 15063 (Creator's Update) then install Microsoft Toolkit of **version 4.0.0**

[image]

Comment: You were right that I did not perform enough research but error message was unclear to me. Overtime I will learn.  I did find the release notes talking about the min target here https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/releases. Next Time I will check the "Breaking changes" Section.

Comment: @Vignesh Yours is a nicely written response. I was using `Tools-->NuGet Package Manager-->Manage NuGet Packages For Solution` and it was giving the following error: `Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Type universe cannot resolve assembly:...` that obviously does not give you the exact cause of the problem. After I ran `PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp -Version 5.1.0` in the console, it gave me the correct cause of the error as shown by `Jean-Marc`. And then your solution helped me resolved the issue. Thank you for helping us.